# Go to definition with LSP

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-ale, lsp, jump, plugin-jedi-vim

I'm trying to use [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) to do "jump-to-definition". For example, if my cursor is on `MLPClassifier`, I want to be able jump to the place where that class is defined in Python code from the imported library `sklearn`.

The [documentation](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32795794/7102572) suggest that I should be able to do this by pressing "\d" while my cursor is on the function/class. However, this does not work.

I think Jedi is installed correctly because autocomplete suggestions seem to work (for example, typing `np.arg` pops up a menu with `argmax`, `argmin`, etc.). Curiously however, running `:help jedi-vim` gives me "`E149: Sorry, no help for jedi-vim`".

---

FYI about my setup:

- I am not using a virtual environment. It's a system-level Python 3.9
- I'm using Asynchronous Lint Engine (ALE) as my Language Server Protocol (LSP) client.

```bash
cd ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/
git clone git@github.com:dense-analysis/ale.git
```

- I'm using [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server) as my LSP server. This uses [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) internally for autocomplete and jump-to-definition.

```bash
pip install python-lsp-server
```

- Here are my plugin-related variables in my `.vimrc`.

```
let g:ale_linters = {'python': ['pylsp']}
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 1
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
packloadall
silent! helptags ALL-
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Did you checked if `\d` jumping to definition of a custom function within your python script? Then you could verify that it works across two custom file linked with import.

Comment: I suspect `sklearn` to be `c` code and that `jedy` can't find the definition. I'll test with `coc` and let you know.

Comment: My assumption was wrong. I does work with `coc` and `VsCode`.

Comment: `\d` seems to not work for me even for function definitions in the same file! Perhaps I am misinterpreting the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the setup with ALE/pylsp/Jedi, we can go to definition by moving a cursor over a function name and typing `:ALEGoToDefinition -vsplit`.

Notice that this is an `ALE` command as opposed to a `Jedi` command. I speculate that this is expected behavior because `ALE` is the LSP client, and therefore it probably must mediate any on-screen changes. If `Jedi` were installed on its own, I would expect that `\d` to work as stated in the Jedi docs.

Figuring out how the various plugins interact with each other via overlapping functionality can be very thorny.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem.

It seems to me that Jedi is able to find the definition of your project methods and functions but is not very good at finding the library definition.

I have a different experience with [`coc-nvim`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) that I encourage your to try.

For Python you'll have to:

1. Install `coc` and
2. Install `coc-pyright` using the Vim command:

```
:CocInstall coc-pyright
```

With `coc-pyright` the `gd` command bring me successfully to the definition of `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier()`.

Comment: Thanks for putting effort to reproduce! (1) How were you able to jump-to-definition within the same project with the ALE setup? Even that doesn't work for me. (2) The jump functionality is one of the core selling points of pylsp/Jedi so I must be misinterpreting the docs or setup incorrectly. Any ideas?. I'm trying to avoid COC because it requires bloat in NodeJS & other dependencies. Also, I thought pyright was a type-checker, not autocompleter/definition-jumper?

Comment: I have a simple Jedi setup and no ALE setup and it works out od the box for me. But I don't recall if I had to install some Python dependencies.